# How to use Variables in PHP Function Argument?

Tags: php, function, arguments

I currently have this code.

```
function outputCalendarByDateRange($client, $startDate="2011-06-22", 
                               $endDate='2011-06-26')
```

I want $startDate and $endDate to reflect today's date and the date three days from now with it automatically updating. I've tried using

```
$startDate=date("Y-m-D")
$endDate=strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($todayDate)) . " +3 days");
```

and

```
$date1=date("Y-m-D")
$date2=strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($todayDate)) . " +3 days");
    function outputCalendarByDateRange($client, $startDate=$date1, 
                               $endDate=$date2)
```

none of these work. How do I make it work?

Thanks!

Comment: Your first `$endDate` is highly overdone. A simple `$endDate = date('Y-m-D', strtotime('+3 days'))` will do.

Comment: @Marc B: Actually, you'd run into problems right around midnight each day doing it that way - better to base it off of $startDate: `$endDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($startDate . '+3 days'))` to handle date changes during execution of the two statements.  It will still be off a day by the time the script gets to the third line of code, but at least the two dates will be off uniformly...

Comment: @Et: in that case, it'd be best to store the raw time value for today, rather than roundtripping everything through strtotime extra times. It's a magical function, but it's NOT efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can't use a statement in a function declaration, but you can set the value to null and check it at runtime:

```
function foo( $bar = null )
{
  if (is_null($bar))
  {
    $bar = 'baz';
  }
  ...code...
}
```

Comment: also, `empty` could be used for the check in some cases where `array()`, `""`, `null`, `false`, etc should trigger the default.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have expressions in the function declaration. But constants could be a workaround for what you want to do.

```
define("FUNC_CAL_DATE1", date("Y-m-D"));
define("FUNC_CAL_DATE2", strtotime(date("Y-m-d",strtotime($to...

function outputCalendarByDateRange($client,
          $startDate=FUNC_CAL_DATE1, $endDate=FUNC_CAL_DATE2) {
```

They are actually expressions too, but are specially handled in this context and work where the `=$date1` wouldn't.

Comment: I'm curious as to whether there could be issues due to caching.

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass variables as default values.  See below for a possible solution to what you're trying to achieve:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $defaultStartDate = date("Y-m-d");
    $defaultEndDate   = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($defaultStartDate . " + 3 days"));

    function outputCalendarByDateRange($client, $startDate="", $endDate="") {
        global $defaultStartDate, $defaultEndDate;

        if ($startDate === "") {
            $startDate = $defaultStartDate;
        }
        if ($endDate === "") {
            $endDate = $defaultEndDate;
        }
        echo "Client: " . $client . "<br />";
        echo "Start Date: " . $startDate . "<br />";
        echo "End Date: " . $endDate . "<br />";
    }

    outputCalendarByDateRange("Test Client");

    echo "<br />";

    outputCalendarByDateRange("Test Client #2", date("Y-m-d", strtotime("2011-06-01")), date("Y-m-d", strtotime("2011-07-01")));

?>
```

Output:

```
Client: Test Client
Start Date: 2011-06-23
End Date: 2011-06-26

Client: Test Client #2
Start Date: 2011-06-01
End Date: 2011-07-01
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have *variable default argument values*, you'll have to solve this in code:

```
function outputCalendarByDateRange($client, $startDate = null, $endDate = null) {
    $startDate = $startDate ? $startDate : date('Y-m-d');
    $endDate = $endDate ? $endDate : date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+3 days'));

    ...
}
```

Calling this function without the second and third argument will use the current date/current date +3, calling it with arguments you can specify your own values.

Answer (score -1):

I'm gonna take a guess and say that you're trying to set $date1 equal to the variable in the function.  That's not necessary, just list them in order. `function outputCalendarByDateRange($client, $date1, $date2)`